# How can I customize UIPopoverController view on iPad?

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

I am looking for a solution to customize PopoverController view in my iPad app. I need to remove the pointing icon along with the popover view and to make the view to the middle of the App window. It should go back to the button from where it is popped when we click on anywhere other than the popover view. USA TODAY app in iPad included such an option. I am not sure about how did they implemented it.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create your own custon view and animate your self.  There is no Appple provided solution